# symbol not found error when trying to call a user defined class using objects in another class

Tags: java

code 1:

```
package hello;
public class hi
{
    int x=30;
}
```

code 2:

```
package hello;
public class hii
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        hi ob=new hi();
        int u= ob.x+33;
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
```

error when compiling code 2:

```
    error:cannot find symbol
hi ob =new hi();
^
error:cannot find symbol
hi ob =new hi();
           ^
```

Comment: go to the upper directory, try `javac -cp src src/hello/hii.java`.

Comment: You need to import the `hi` class in your `hii` class.

Comment: Your code works for me. No compiler errors. How are you compiling?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the class:

```
import hello.hi;
```

Comment: Both classes are in the same package. No need for an import.